# Canvas Context.drawImage() is leaving behind duplicates of Sprite on UpdatePosition()

Tags: javascript, loops, rendering, sprite

I've been experimenting with a basic game loop with HTML's Canvas element. Numerous tutorials online don't go into enough detail with the concepts of rendering and canvas.ctx (context).

What I'm trying to do is something very simple: **Render an image on a canvas element and, on keydown, update its position and render it at the new location, making it move across the screen.** Basically, what every video game does with its sprites.

I've been told through these tutorials that `ctx.drawImage(image, x, y, ...)` will work for this. However, what ends up happening in my version is essentially what happens when you win a game of solitaire on windows. **It repeats the sprite's image as if it's creating a brand new sprite each time the game loops.** The sprite itself doesn't move, a new sprite seems to be generated to the left/right/etc of the original one. I understand that I'm calling `ctx.drawImage(...)` every time I'm iterating through the game loop. However, this didn't happen when I used `ctx.clearRect(...)`. It worked precisely how I expected it to. I'm not exactly sure why creating a rectangle with ctx works while creating an image doesn't.

My question is: **Is there a way to simply update the position of the sprite without creating a brand new version of it every single loop?**

Here's my relevant code:

```
let lastRender = 0; // For the general loop

let image = new Image();
image.src = "/img/image.png";

let state = {
    pressedKeys: {
        // left, right, up, down: false
    },

    position: {
        x: canvas.width / 2,
        y: canvas.width / 2
    },

    speed: 20
}

let pepsi = new Sprite({
    img: image,
    width: 100,
    height: 100
)};


function Sprite (options) {
    this.img = options.img;
    this.width = options.width;
    this.height = options.height;

    this.render = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(
        this.img,
        state.position.x,
        state.position.y
        )
    }
}

function updatePosition(progress) {
        //pressedKeys is just an object that relates WASD to the key codes 
        //     and their respective directions, it's ignorable

        if (state.pressedKeys.left) {
            state.position.x -= state.speed;
        }

        if (state.pressedKeys.right) {
            state.position.x += state.speed;
        }

        if (state.pressedKeys.up) {
            state.position.y -= state.speed;
        }

        if (state.pressedKeys.down) {
            state.position.y += state.speed;
        }
}


function draw() {
    pepsi.render();
}

function loop(timestamp) {
    let progress = timestamp - lastRender;

    update(progress) // <-- Updates position, doesn't touch draw()

    draw(); // <-- Runs pepsi.render(); each loop

    lastRender = timestamp;             
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop); 
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(loop); // for the general loop
```

If you have any qualms with the way this project is set up (for example, using the state.position for *each* Sprite), then I'd be glad to hear them in addition to the solution to my problem. Not in isolation. I got most of this code from contextless, non-specific online tutorials, but I understand most of it, save for the rendering.

Also, if you've seen this kind of question before and are on the fence about saying *"Possible duplicate of {Borderline Tangentially-Related Post from Four Years Ago}"*, then here's some advice: Just answer the question again. It literally does nothing negative to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solitaire smearing effect that you are getting, comes from the fact each frame is being drawn over the top of the last one. The canvas doesn't get cleared automatically between frames.

You mentioned that you have used clearRect, the use of clearRect is to clear all the pixels in the specified rectangle.

So if you put `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)` in the draw function before `pepsi.render()`, that should clear the canvas before drawing the next frame.